# Not persisting value with transaction

Tags: ethereumjs, ropsten, ethereumjs-tx

I have a contract that looks like this -

```
contract Calculator {
    uint public result;
    event Added(address caller, uint a, uint b, uint res);

    constructor() public {
        result = 777;
    }

    function add(uint a, uint b) public returns (uint, address) {
        result = a + b;
        emit Added(msg.sender, a, b, result);
        return (result, msg.sender);
    }
}
```

So I expected that invoking `add` function will add supplied two numbers and replace the old value persisted in `result` variable. But my invocation produces -

```
Before:  777
Transaction hash: 0xeef135d7838a2f6093918d3b055fe5ea2ce4c3c3c54c8a8c8328def95465f8e4
After:  777
```

Above transaction hash is valid and you can see [details here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xeef135d7838a2f6093918d3b055fe5ea2ce4c3c3c54c8a8c8328def95465f8e4).

Here is my code -

```
async function addWithTx() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const senderAccount = rtUtil.getFirstAccount();
        const contract = await rtUtil.getCalculatorContract(senderAccount.calculatorContractAddress);

        let result = await contract.methods.result().call();
        console.log("Before: ", result);

        const accountPkBuffer = Buffer.from(senderAccount.accountPk, "hex");
        const data = await contract.methods.add(5, 74).encodeABI();

        const web3 = rtUtil.getWeb3();
        const taxCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAccount.accountAddress);

        const txData = {
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(taxCount),
            to: rtUtil.getSecondAccount().calculatorContractAddress,
            value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')),
            gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100000),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('6', 'gwei')),
            data: data
        };

        const tx = new EthereumTx(txData, {chain: 'ropsten'});
        tx.sign(accountPkBuffer);
        const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
        const raw = web3.utils.toHex(serializedTx);

        const transaction = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw);

        result = await contract.methods.result().call();
        console.log("After: ", result);

        resolve(transaction);
    });
}

addWithTx()
    .then(receipt => {
        console.log("Transaction hash: ", receipt.transactionHash);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

My questions are -

1. Why the value is not persisted? Even though its a valid transaction and mined.
2. If i don't supply the `to` field then a new `contract creation` [transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x2c97646f5176db49ebbec9f7a00c2610482b827c) is created. Why the transaction is creating a new contract? What is the content of the contract?

Comment: Likely you are not sending transaction to a deployed contract. Either the contract is deployed or you are sending the transaction to a wrong address.

Comment: I doubt if that is the case. I am sending the transaction to `0xF5247E59cbB11FD3a5F377E608f25c641E84f37A` and you can find it on Ropsten. Also by `sending the transaction to wrong address` if you mean the account address, then I don't think that is correct either, because here is the address I am using `0x136930AdF29C6425Fa19eA660b5A22c26bdaAFE8`, and you can see that transaction on that account has been created as well. Of course the transaction signature is being verified which is signed by account private key. So I don't think any of those are wrong.

Comment: Thank you Jahid. Looks good. Can you verify your contract source code on EtherScan? In this case, you would get symbolic output from each transaction and you will see exactly what happens within your contract. Here is an example of symbolic output on Etherscan: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x35c178abd163767fe3087eb928de91e3a7041e38b7d8992d499cde30ceb1c119

Comment: I am bit confused. The link you gave is a transaction details, but not contract. Secondly, I actually dont know how to verify contract. I mean I just invoked the getter function `result` method, and which returns the default value. So isn't that enough to say that the contract is deployed and function is executed?

Comment: @JahidShohel Querying the contract `result` changed to 79 = 74 + 5 as expected, so the scripts is querying before the transaction is mined.

Comment: @Ismael how did you query? Because I just ran `let result = await contract.methods.result().call();`, which still gives me 777 (the default value)

Comment: @JahidShohel I used remix + metamask instantiating Calculator contract at the address [`0xd420ae7e..f3`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xd420ae7e9f351fe780eb515bd6d2af0dc1625bf3), then reading `result` I got the expected output. Looking state changes from previous transactions like [0x207c6cd4..2d](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x207c6cd4111acb38785604d2d3ce7c89f8dc09026e3b837b69e94b5f240ea92d#statechange) you can see that the content from one slot is modified to 0x4f = 79. Other transaction have the same input so `result` isn't modified.

Answer (score 0):

1. My hunch is that the code on ropsten may not match what you've shown, or the ABI being used by web3's Contract method isn't up to date.
2. the contract "code" that is stored is just `0x` (so: nothing), and its address is generated from the from `account` and its `nonce`. It's just what happens when you don't have a `to` address.

Comment: I just executed `let result = await contract.methods.result().call();` and it is still giving me 777 (i mean the default value). So according to your loging, isn't that should return 79 now?

Comment: Hm, in that case I'm not sure what the issue is. Perhaps your contract code on ropsten isn't exactly as you expect for some reason.